# Организация приложения в Go

Tags: json, golang

Написал небольшое приложение, суть которого: имеется файл .json, там список пользователей, с которыми из консоли можно совершать следующие действия:

- редактирование пользователя
- удаление
- создание нового пользователя
- показ пользователя по его ИД

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как правильно организовать структуру данного приложения, ибо я все писал в main.go, и все получилось трудночитаемо. Или например дать ссылку, где про это написано, может быть даже независимо от языка программирования.

Comment: https://github.com/golang-standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единого стандарта нет. В качестве источников вдохновения, можете посмотреть на:

- [Стандартную библиотеку](https://golang.org/pkg/).
- Большие проекты типа [moby (aka Docker)](https://github.com/moby/moby) или [gogs](https://github.com/gogs/gogs). Сотни их.
- Статьи Дейва Чейни: [[1]](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/01/five-suggestions-for-setting-up-a-go-project), [[2]](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/08/20/solid-go-design), ещё много там.
- [Видео доклада](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzTcsI6tn-0) <s>Брайана Кителсена</s> Эшли Макнамара.